# Bootstrap 4 Layout not working as expected when used with forms

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I am working with Bootstrap 4 on a form. Now, when using the form along with the grid classes, it does not actually work like its supposed to. The output can be seen here http://www.henryspike.tk/testform

What I had expected was to see the whole 12 columns divided into 4-4-4 each containing an input field but it stacks up.

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 offset-md-1">
                        <div class="row">
                            <form class="form">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="eg. John Doe" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Name</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="someone@example.com" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="username">Name</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="eg. JDoe12" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`col-` should always be the *immediate* child of `row`..

http://www.codeply.com/go/moFmNMMuPs

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form class="row form">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="eg. John Doe" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="someone@example.com" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="eg. JDoe12" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```